# Calculate the expected cost

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

A headphone manufacturer guarantees that the company will repair any headphone that is defective within one year warranty period for free. Past records showed that 5% of their headphone needed repair during the warranty period. The company sold 30 headphones last January. If the average cost of repairing a headphone is 70$, calculate the expected cost the manufacturer needs to bear in repairing not more than four headphones.

Can anyone help me with this question because i'm confused if i need to use approximation or not.
Thank your for your help :)

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What does "the expected cost the manufacturer needs to bear in repairing not more than four headphones." mean?

Comment: Regardless of what it is you mean, exactly, there are only $30$ trials here so there should be no difficulty working with the binomial distribution (as opposed to a normal approximation or whatever other sort of approximation you had in mind).

Comment: So at most four headphones need to be repair?

Comment: yes but i dont know how to calculate the cost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

The expected cost are $\mathbb E(C)=70\cdot \sum\limits_{k=0}^4 P(X=k)\cdot k$, where $X\sim Bin(30, 0.05)$ and $k$ are the number of headphones need to be repaired.

Comment: i got 68$ .....

Comment: I got almost the same: $\mathbb E(C)\approx 68.9055\approx69$. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=70*sum_%28k%3D0%29%5E4+%2830+choose+k%29*0.05%5Ek*0.95%5E%2830-k%29)

Comment: The problem is too vaguely stated to be sure, but surely you'd have to pay to repair $4$ even if more than $4$ broke.  The way you've summed this...if $4$ broken ones were detected the seller could save  lot of money by breaking one more.